# weird behaviour with svelte store and routify $params,

Tags: javascript, store, lifecycle, reactive, svelte

Im doing some kind of a forum where all the messages are linked to each other in some way. To save DB reads, I'm storing messages in a $messageStore as $messageStore[messageId]. 
I'm using routify's $params to navigate from /message/id1 to /message/id2 etc, where each page contains the message identified in the $params, but also other linked messages that might or might not already be in the store..

My problem is:

1st, the components are not unmounting, so I trigger that when $params change by flicking a value for 1ms that disables the rendering of the main component and forces the init() function to check what it needs to fetch on the DB or not.. It is ugly, it seems to work so far, but I bet this will fail one day depending on the machine it runs on.

2nd, after doing that, I ran into things that I didn't understand. The $messageStore doesn't change while the page is changing, but all of a sudden I get plenty of undefined value. It seems like the $params are going from value1 to nothing to value2. 
Also if I check in the init() function if($messageStore[$params.id].someKey==="someValue"), it doesn't pass, although I'm sure it's in the store.

If I did

`console.log($messageStore[$params.id].someKey)` `console.log($messageStore[$params.id].someKey==="someValue")` `if($messageStore[$params.id].someKey==="someValue"){console.log('passed')}else{console.log("failed")}`

I got:

```
"someValue"
true
"failed"
```

It is like if console.log() is not giving the result at the time of execution..

Before using Routify, I had the same king of stuff with svelte-spa-router, so It might be something that I don't get with svelte and changing store values and order of execution..

I seemed to find a way around by passing the params with a scoped prop from the top component that flickers on page change, but if somebody could teach me something there, I would be really grateful..

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what problem 1 is. To get started I'm just going to throw some bullet points at you which may or may not help. I hope that's okay.

1. Reactivity should be handled with `$:`. Ie. to listen for changes on a store you need to write. `$: console.log($mystore)`
2. Routify 1.8 beta supports serviceworkers, offline availability, prefetching of external assets and caching. This might help with duplicate requests to your API.
3. > I'm using routify's $params to navigate from /message/id1 to /message/id2 etc

   ^ What does this mean?
4. Could you create a replication of the issue on Codesandbox?

I wish I were of more help, but the issue feels somewhat black-boxy.

Comment: hi Jake. Thanks for your answer.
My problem with problem 1 was that $messageStore is a big object to which I apply changes  while the user is on the page, and I don't want everything to be re calculated each time.
 I would have been happy to use onMount, but the components didn't seem to unmount between two different pages based on the same components.
The question would be: How to replace onMount(), when the components do not unmount, and not based on the values they use. 
Or how to trigger a re-render on params change?

Comment: I'll look at routify1.8 beta, yes, I'll try to see how codesandbox works..

Comment: You should be able to use `$beforeUrlChange` and/or `$afterPageLoad` to trigger a rerender. If this is a common usecase, we could add a `$isChangingPage` helper.

Comment: I think my problem came from me not knowing about reactive statements.. It works well now ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think I do the same thing with images, but I'm a little confused as to your use case. For me, I have a folder `gallery` white an `index.svelte` and a `[image].svelte`. So you can go to `gallery/1`, `gallery/2`, etc. and see different images. Instead of using params, just use `export let image` (or in your case `export let id`, to access the message id. Then you can use your id to get the correct index in your $messagestore with something like:

```
//this will get the the url param
export let id
//this will change every time your id chages, i.e. message/1 to message/2
$: if (id) { 
    getIndex();
}

 async function getIndex() {
//make sure the message store has finished loading, you'd set this in the store
await waitFor(() => $messageStoreLoaded === true);

sIndex = await $messageStore.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
//if for whatever reason the message is not in the store, do some error handling
if (sIndex == -1) sIndex = -2;

//keep a store of what index you're on, this is another writable store
await messageStoreIndex.update(n => (n = sIndex));

//load the new message data from the store
newMessage = $storePics[$storePicsIndex];
}

function waitFor(conditionFunction) {
  const poll = (resolve) => {
    if (conditionFunction()) resolve("The Thing Finished");
//you can get rid of the console.log, and change the millisenconds to whatever, I usually stick to 100 to 400 for most things
    else console.log("Still Wating..."), setTimeout((_) => poll(resolve), 200);
  };
  return new Promise(poll);
}
```

Hopefully that gives you a starting point. You can make one database call to populate your messageStore, and then just keep track of what index you're on with the function.

Comment: ah thanks !  Basically i'm building a forum structured as a tree, where the main page is "/message/[id]/[sortKidsBy.value]/[sortKidsBy.order]"
What I try to do on each page is: 
1 - react to the new address
2-check if we have the main message in the store
3-once we got it, check if we had the same request already-and get the children id's
4-fetch the children's from store or db

Comment: What is your waitFor function? a custom one in your store?

Comment: this: $: if (id) { 
    getIndex();
}. is something I didn't know I could do

Comment: Ah! yes, the waitFor is custom, just a simple polling from another stackoverflow quesiton :) I added it to the answer. Let me know if that gets you started, I can try to help if you run into an issue.

Comment: yep that was a good answer, thanks. It pushed me to buy the book "svelte and sapper in action" to try to consolidate what I thought I understood by taking pieces here and there on the web. There is a lot to learn starting on my own from nearly scratch..